# How to monitor size and last update time for Kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Is it possible using Java to determine the size of a topic (bytes) and the time of the last update (in timestamp)? Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend using SSH commands for that (you can use Jsch in Java)